# How to load D3.js GeoJSON and CSV into CodeIgniter

Tags: javascript, html, codeigniter, d3.js, svg

The problems that i have : 
Can't load GeoJSON and CSV which loaded from the script.js

this is the structure of my website in localhost

localhost/BMKG

so my question is

How to load csv and geojson map from my JS, but CodeIgniter always recognized it as link

script.js

```
var width = 1920,
  height = 1080,
  populationDomain;

var colorRange = ["#532E26", "#9E4825", "#E07A26", "#F2B526", "#EDE626", "#E4FD7E", "#9CDA9B", "#55A252", "#26622F"];
var populationDomain = [0, 21, 51, 101, 151, 201, 301, 401, 501];

// Create SVG element
var svg = d3.select("body").insert("svg", "p")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height * 0.8)
  .attr("class", "map");

// Projection and path
var projection = d3.geoMercator()
  .center([110, -7.5])
  .scale(width * 12)
  .translate([width / 2, height / 2]);

var path = d3.geoPath().projection(projection);

// Asynchronous tasks, load topojson map and data
d3.queue()
  .defer(d3.json, "data/jawa-tengah.json")
  .defer(d3.csv, "data/data.csv")
  .await(ready);

// Callback function
function ready(error, data, population) {
  if (error) throw error;

  // population data
  var populationData = {};

  population.forEach(function (d) { populationData[d.id] = +d.population; });

  // Color
  var populationColor = d3.scaleThreshold()
    .domain(populationDomain)
    .range(colorRange);

  var g = svg.append("g");

  // Draw the map
  g.selectAll("path")
    .attr("class", "city")
    .data(data.features)
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("d", path)
    .attr("stroke", "black")
    .attr("stroke-width", "0.2")
    .attr("fill", "white")
    .transition().duration(2000)
    .delay(function (d, i) { return i * 5; })
    .ease(d3.easeLinear)
    .attr("fill", function (d) {
      return populationColor(populationData[d.properties.kabkot]);
    });

  g.selectAll("path")
    .append("title")
    .text(function (d) {
      return d.properties.kabkot + " : " + populationData[d.properties.kabkot];
    });
}

d3.select(window).on("resize", resize);

function resize() {
  width = window.innerWidth;
  height = window.innerHeight;

  projection.scale(width * 1.2)
    .translate([width / 2, height / 2]);

  d3.select("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height * 0.8);

  d3.selectAll("path")
    .attr("d", path);
}
```

I load my file like this in CodeIgniter

```
<!-- D3.js Source -->
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/topojson.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-geo-projection.v2.min.js"></script>

<!-- Script -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url() . 'assets/js/script.js' ?>"></script>
```

i already tried to set the file as a gist link in github and it could work. but i want it so i could load it locally.

Thanks.

Comment: you only need to have the base path set, so if you are on local machine and using localhost:8080/MY_PROJECT/ then you have to set your paths accordingly like this: `.defer(d3.json, '/MY_PROJECT/' + "/data/jawa-tengah.json")...`  something like that.

Comment: what if i want to load those files but it depends on its ID in MySql, for example: if i open #1 data it will load #1.csv, if i open #2 data it will load #2.csv and so on. How can i do that? Thank you

Comment: nevermind, i solved by using   .defer(d3.csv, '/MY_PROJECT/' + "upload/data/" + document.getElementById("fileinput").value + ".csv")

Comment: Just saw your comment, glade you solved it :)